# Incluir nuevo campo en consulta find() CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp

He incluido un nuevo campo boleano en una tabla de vinos, `dist_exclusiva`, he creado tambien el campo en el formulario de creación y de edición. El problema lo tengo cuando se ejecutan las consultas, no recoge el nuevo campo, la consulta parece predefinida y no encuentro la manera de configurarla, tengo entendido que es en el modelo, pero no se como hacerlo. Soy nuevo con `CAKEPHP`.

Este es el controlador

```
  public function admin_edit($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    $title_for_layout  = 'Administrador';
    $title_page = 'Edit Vino';
    $description_page = 'editar Vino del sitio';
    $this->menu[$this->indexmenu]['active'] = true;

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please provide el id Vino.'),'flash_notification',array('type'=>'danger','icon'=>'fa-times fa-lg' ));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    $vino = $this->Vino->findById($id);



    if (!$vino) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid vino ID Provided.'),'flash_notification',array('type'=>'danger','icon'=>'fa-times fa-lg' ));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $this->Vino->id = $id;

        if ($this->request->data['Vino']['imagen']['error'] == 0 && $this->request->data['Vino']['imagen']['size'] > 0){

            // pathes to upload
            //set new name to uplaoded file
            $extcion = ($this->Upload->ext($this->request->data['Vino']['imagen']['name']));
            $NewFileName = $this->Tool->getCodigo().".".$extcion;
            //$NewFileName = $filee['name'];
            // upload file to path
            // here in parameter "image" you can change it that if you want to upload another extension

            if ($this->Upload->upload($this->request->data['Vino']['imagen'], 'img/upload', 'image', $NewFileName, 'vinos'))
                $this->request->data['Vino']['imagen'] = $NewFileName;
            else{
                //set log error if there is problem in uploading
                $this->log(print ('Uploading Error in File'));
            }
        }
        else
            unset($this->request->data['Vino']['imagen']);

        $this->request->data['Vino']['copa'] = str_replace(",", ".", $this->request->data['Vino']['copa']);
        $this->request->data['Vino']['terraza'] = str_replace(",", ".", $this->request->data['Vino']['terraza']);

        if ($this->Vino->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Se actualizo el Vino.'),'flash_notification',array('type'=>'success','icon'=>'fa-check fa-lg' ));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }else
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your Vino.'),'flash_notification',array('type'=>'danger','icon'=>'fa-times fa-lg' ));
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $vino;
        $this->request->data['Vino']['copa'] = str_replace(".", ",", $vino['Vino']['copa']);
        $this->request->data['Vino']['terraza'] = str_replace(".", ",", $vino['Vino']['terraza']);
    }

    $data = array(
        'menus' => $this->menu
    );

    /*$this->Denominacion->virtualFields = array(
        'full_name' => "CONCAT(Denominacion.nombre, ' / ', Denominacion.descripcion)"
    );*/
    $denominacions = $this->Denominacion->find('list', array('fields' => array('Denominacion.id', 'Denominacion.nombre'), 'order' => array('Denominacion.nombre asc')));
    $cartas = $this->Carta->find('list', array('fields' => array('Carta.id', 'Carta.nombre')));
    $typo = array('Blanco' => 'Blanco', 'Champagne' => 'Champagne', 'Cava' => 'Cava', 'Rosado' => 'Rosado', 'Tinto' => 'Tinto');
    $this->set($data);
    $this->set(compact('typo', 'cartas','denominacions','title_for_layout', 'title_page', 'description_page'));
}
```

la AppModel

```
class AppModel extends Model {

    public function generateSlug($title = null, $id = null) {
        if (!$title) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Title'));
        }

        $title = strtolower($title);
        $slug  = Inflector::slug($title, '-');

        $conditions = array();
        $conditions[$this->alias . '.slug'] = $slug;

        if ($id) {
            $conditions[$this->primaryKey. ' NOT'] = $id;
        }

        $total = $this->find('count', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'recursive' => 0));
        if ($total > 0) {
            for ($number = 2; $number > 0; $number ++) {
                $conditions[$this->alias . '.slug'] = $slug . '-' . $number;

                $total = $this->find('count', array('conditions' => $conditions, 'recursive' => 0));
                if ($total == 0) {
                    return $slug . '-' . $number;
                }
            }
        }

        return $slug;
    }
}
```

el modelo

```
class Vino extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Vino';

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Carta' => array(
        'className'    => 'Carta',
        'foreignKey'   => 'carta_id'
    ),
    'Denominacion' => array(
        'className'    => 'Denominacion',
        'foreignKey'   => 'denominacion_id'
    )
);
```

Gracias de antemano

Añado vista del formulario

```
   <div class="page-header">
<h1>
    <?php echo $title_page ?>
    <small>
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
        <?php echo $description_page ?>
    </small>
</h1>
</div><!-- /.page-header -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Vino', array('type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form','id' => 'myform', 'action' => 'add'));?>
    <!-- #section:elements.form -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Vino</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('bodega', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'bodega...', 'type' => 'text', 'required' => true)); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Bodega</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('lugar', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'lugar...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Crianza</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('crianza', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'crianza', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">uva</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('grapes', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'graprs', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Botella</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('precio', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'Precio...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Copa</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('copa', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'Copa...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <!--div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Tienda</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('terraza', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'Terraza...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div-->
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Distribucion</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('hosteleria', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'Distribucion...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="categoria">Distribución Exclusiva</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('dist_exclusiva',array('label'=> false, 'class' => "", 'type'=>'checkbox')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Eno-precio</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('enoprecio', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'Eno-precio...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Outlet</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('outlet', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'Outlet...', 'type' => 'text')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="categoria">Tipo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('typo',array('label'=> false, 'class' => "col-xs-10 col-sm-5", 'type'=>'select', 'options' => $typo, 'required' => true)); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="categoria">Carta</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('carta_id',array('label'=> false, 'name' => "data[Vino][carta_id]", 'empty' => array(0 => ''), 'class' => "col-xs-10 col-sm-5", 'type'=>'select')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="categoria">Denominacion</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('denominacion_id',array('label'=> false, 'class' => "col-xs-10 col-sm-5", 'type'=>'select', 'required' => true)); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="categoria">Add Carta texto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('add_carta',array('label'=> false, 'class' => "", 'type'=>'checkbox')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="categoria">Add Tv</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('add_tv',array('label'=> false, 'class' => "", 'type'=>'checkbox')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Imagen</label>
        <?php if(!empty($this->data['Vino']['imagen'])):
            echo $this->Form->input('imagen', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5 logo file-loading', 'type' => 'file', 'accept' => 'image/*', 'data-buttonText' => "Find file"));
        else:
            echo $this->Form->input('imagen', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5 logo file-loading', 'type' => 'file', 'accept' => 'image/*', 'data-buttonText' => "Find file", 'required' => true));
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Descripción</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('description', array('div' => 'col-sm-9', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'col-xs-10 col-sm-5', 'placeholder' => 'texto...', 'rows' => 8)); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="clearfix form-actions">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-110"></i>
                Guardar
            </button>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <button class="btn resetform" type="reset">
                <i class="ace-icon fa fa-undo bigger-110"></i>
                Reset
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
 </div><!-- /.col -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Añadi el codigo de la vista, pero no consigo que quede como bloque de codigo, disculpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se agrega un nuevo campo en la base de datos debes de eliminar la memoria cache del modelo para que así este pueda tomar el cambio , luego agregas los inputs en tu vista add y edit con el nombre que guardaste el campo.
También es buena practica eliminar la cache del navegador.

Puedes ir a las ruta app/tmp/cache/models y eliminar o por consola con los siguientes comandos

```
rm -f app/tmp/cache/models/*

rm -f app/tmp/cache/views/*
```

agregas esto en las vistas

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('dist_exclusiva',array('label'=> false, 'class' => "", 'type'=>'checkbox')); ?>
```